# jquery .each function using 2 selectors and adding value from selectors as key value pair to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jquery .each function utilizing 2 selectors. When pushing the values to an array it adds them as each selector value as its own entry into the array.

in example `array(100,casement,200,glider)`

what I am trying to do is add them in key value pair in an array such as

`array(100=>casement, 200=>glider)`

What do I need to change to make this happen?

```
 <input name="windowNum"><input name="windowList">
 <input name="windowNum"><input name="windowList">
 <input name="windowNum"><input name="windowList">
 <input name="windowNum"><input name="windowList">

<script>
function getFields(){
  $("input[name='windowNum'], input[name='windowList']").each(function() {

      var winList = $(this).val();

      windowList.push(winList);

      //I want an array output like this from the 2 fields
      //windowList.push(input[name='windowNum'] : input[name='windowList'])
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Kindly add the your html structure. I think you just need to loop on each `input[name='windowNum']` and look for its pair `input[name='windowNum']`. Instead of looping in both and adding them individually.

Comment: what is `casement` and `glider` ?

Comment: @decpk they are just random names for windows in the example of what would be in the array

Comment: what exactly do you want or what what should be the output that you are expecting? Please add in the question...

Comment: You could just run 2 loops, 1 for the key and 1 for the value

Comment: Try this idea `$("input[name='windowNum']").each(function() {

      var key = $(this).val();

      windowList[key] = $(this).next().val();
});` you may refer to this [link](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

Comment: @iamrafaelperez this does not work. First off it only untilizes one selector which I need 2 to gather both fields of data. and when used how you suggested it leaves the value in the key value pair empty `"test a": ""
​
"test b": ""
​
"test c": ""`

Comment: @Rylee I did try this however was unsuccessful at it

Answer (score 0):

It is working on my end. Try to test it into this code snippet. Or I probably did not understand your expected output.

```js
var windowList = {};

function getFields(){
  $("input[name='windowNum']").each(function() {
      var key = $(this).val();        
      windowList[key] = $(this).next().val(); 
  });
  
  console.log(windowList);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="windowNum"><input name="windowList"><br>
 <input name="windowNum"><input name="windowList"><br>
 <input name="windowNum"><input name="windowList"><br>
 <input name="windowNum"><input name="windowList">
 
 <button type="button" onclick="getFields()">Test</button>
```

Comment: you arent even getting all the data from the fields. Its `$("input[name='windowNum'], input[name='windowList']").each` not `$("input[name='windowNum']").each`

Comment: I dont think you need to loop to all your fields. I think you just need to loop to the key fields using `$("input[name='windowNum']").each` and get the value using `$(this).next().val()` to form the key value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` instead of `each`

```js
let arr = [100, casement, 200, glider];

arr = arr.map((v, i) = > {
    if (i % 2 === 1 || !arr[i + 1]) return null;
    return `${v}=>${arr[i + 1]}`;
}).filter(Boolean);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Here is what I did.

```
$("input[name='windowNum'], input[name='windowList']").each(function() {

    var winList = $(this).val();

    windowList_x.push(winList);
});

for (let i = 0; i < windowList_x.length; i+=2) {

var wNum = windowList_x[i];
var wName = windowList_x[i + 1];

windowList.push({number: wNum, window: wName});

}
```

It outputs

```
Array
0: Object { number: "101", window: "test a" }
1: Object { number: "102", window: "test b" }
2: Object { number: "103", window: "test c" }
3: Object { number: "104", window: "test d" }
length: 4
```